# How to separate multi progress percentage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, progress

I can show one progress percentage when uploading multiple files.How to separate progress percentage if I uploading multiple files?

```
//multi upload
fileuploadHandler = () => {

    const storageRef = fire.storage().ref();
    this.state.file.forEach((file) => {

      storageRef
          .child(`images/${file.name}`)
          .put(file).then((snapshot) => {
            var uploadTask = storageRef.child(`images/${file.name}`).put(file);
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) =>{
                var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            var    fixprogress = progress.toFixed(2);
                this.setState({fixprogress});
                console.log('Upload is ' + fixprogress + '% done');
            })


      })

    });

  }
```

and this my button and show progress percentage.

```
<button className="loginBtn2 loginBtn--U" onClick={this.fileuploadHandler}>  Upload!</button> 
                            uploading {this.state.fixprogress}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the second parameter passed to `forEach` and you get an index. Use this to identify the different files and display them somehow differently, like this:

```
//multi upload
fileuploadHandler = () => {

    const storageRef = fire.storage().ref();
    // USE THE SECOND PARAMETER: INDEX
    this.state.file.forEach( (file, index) => {

      storageRef
          .child(`images/${file.name}`)
          .put(file).then((snapshot) => {
            var uploadTask = storageRef.child(`images/${file.name}`).put(file);
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) =>{
                var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            var    fixprogress = progress.toFixed(2);
            // NOW USE IT TO DISPLAY SPECIFIC STATE FOR THAT FILE
            this.setState( { progress: { ( "file" + index ) : fixprogress} } );
            // LOG THE STATE
            console.log('Upload for file number #' + index + ' is ' + fixprogress + '% done');
            })
      })
    });
  }
```

In this case you then retrieve the `this.state.progress.file0` to get the progress of the first file.